# Javascript window.open not working in code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a menu user control inside my master page. After login, menu will be populated. When the Print Receipt Menu is clicked, it will open a Receipt in another window.
i try with the below code but it seems not working from code behind. It works if i put into html instead of code behind.

```
Dim sOnClick as string = "onclick='javascript:window.open('http://localhost:10101/Project/Sales/PrintReceipt.aspx?id=12345', '_blank','width=420,height=400,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=yes,resizable=No');'" 

Dim sbMenu As New StringBuilder
sbMenu.Insert(0, "<li><a href='#' " & sOnClick & ">Print Receipt</a></li>")
```

Answer (score 0):

To call you java script function code behind do like this

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "AKey", "YOUR JAVA SCRIPT FUNCTION", true);

Answer (score 0):

Try using `response` stream instead:

```
Response.Write("<script>");
Response.Write("window.open('https://www.google.com','_blank')");
Response.Write("</script>");
```

You can also use the below for your `<a>` tag:

`Target= "_blank"`